# SQLite Cursor returning the value for one column as the value for all columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv, cursor

I am attempting to read from an SQLite database I have created containing information on UK universities.

The table has the following columns:

```
Institution
Rank_2017
Guardian_score100
Satisfied_with_course
Satisfied_with_teaching
Satisfied_with_feedback
Student_to_staff_ratio
Average_entry_tariff
Career_after_6_months
```

I have populated the table from a CSV file, and then attempted to call a `getUni()` method that will return the information in each of the columns, and use them to build a `University` object, however when I check the values of each member variable of `University`, the name and rank have been set appropriately, however every variable after that has also been set to the value of `Rank_2017`.

**getUni() Method**

```
public University getUni(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_UNIVERSITIES, COLUMNS, " Institution = ?",
            new String[] { id }, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }


    System.out.println("@@@" + cursor.getCount() + "@@@");
    University uni = new University();

    if(cursor != null){
        uni.setUni_name(cursor.getString(0));
        uni.setRank(cursor.getString(1));
        uni.setGuardianScore(cursor.getString(2));
        uni.setCourseSatisfaction(cursor.getString(3));
        uni.setTeachingSatisfaction(cursor.getString(4));
        uni.setFeedbackSatisfaction(cursor.getString(5));
        uni.setStudentStaffRatio(cursor.getString(6));
        uni.setAverageEntryTariff(cursor.getString(7));
        uni.setCareerAfterSixMonths(cursor.getString(8));

    }
    // return University
    return uni;
}
```

After calling `cursor.getColumnCount()` i can see that it returns 10 columns as expected, however something isn't quite right.

For example, if I call `University uni = getUni("Glasgow");` , it will assign both the `University` `name`, and `rank_2017` correctly, however assign each member variable after that the same as `rank_2017`.

**CSV row example:**

```
Glasgow,26,70.8,89.3,91.6,67.3,14.5,478.4,78.5
```

Any help solving this issue would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect when you imported the CSV file, it didn't work correctly.  Perhaps you didn't specify a separator, and SQLite created a table for you with only one column.  Or it populated the table strangely, and your SQL adapter is "helping" in a surprising way.  That could happen if for instance your CSV file had some whitespace.

I would use the SQLite shell to verify that the Glassgow row appears as expected in the database.  That at least will let you distinguish between SQLite issues and Java library issues (if any).

HTH.